# Changing interface settings in Docker

Tags: networking, docker

I'm trying to disable TCP Segmentation Offload (TSO) of the loopback interface in a `Docker` image. I use the command:

```
sudo ethtool -K lo tso off
```

And I keep getting the message:

`Cannot set device feature settings: Operation not permitted.`

I read that the network interface of the Docker image bridges the interface of the host machine. So, I thought that perhaps I needed to change the setting in the host interface, but that neither doesn't work.

Anyway, the loopback interface doesn't need to be bridged, right? It can be virtualized in the image, as the packets don't leave the guest machine, right?

I'm thinking about recompiling the kernel of the image (I'm using Docker's default Ubuntu image, which is the backports distribution). I could set these properties in the image and commit it to my Docker repository. I would like to know your opinion on this, before getting too far?

Does anybody know an easier way to do this in Docker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the new Docker 0.6 [new](http://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/) `privileged mode` option.

Running the container in this mode allowed me to change the guest interface settings:

```
docker run --privileged -it <image>
sudo ethtool -K lo tso off
```